# js template render works... but then page reloads and erases its effect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

(Running Rails 4.1.1.) The functionality I'm trying to build gradually refines a search by having each user selection from a dropdown add another dropdown control to the page, which has more options to narrow the search down even further. It works, except that just after that control is added (using js events and rendering of a js template) the whole page reloads and we're back to square one. I don't understand what triggers that reload.

So, I have a view with a Bootstrap(3.2.0) button dropdown on it. When the user selects something from that dropdown, a js 'click' event fires. That event runs a JQuery 'get()' which requests the next control (called a 'wedge' in this case). The CoffeeScript for the event handler looks like this:

```
$("li.wedge_#{wedge.id}_link").click ->
  output_wedge = $(this).data("outputwedge")
  $.get( "/wedges/" + output_wedge + '.js' )
```

And the console shows something like:

```
Started GET "/wedges/2.js" for 127.0.0.1
```

The wedge's show.js template runs and renders a partial containing the new wedge control and adds it to the page. The wedge.js template looks like this:

```
$('#after_wedges').before("<%= escape_javascript( render partial: 'wedge', locals: {wedge: @wedge}) %>")
```

And all of that is fine, except that a moment after the new control appears, the whole page reloads, but I don't understand what part of the process triggers that reload. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add `e.preventDefault()` at the top of `click` handler. `e` would come from `.click(e)`.

Also, `wedges.js` should be `wedges.js.erb`, if its not already.

Comment: Not only does that prevent the reload (thanks!), it also gives me a place to start understanding what was happening. That wedge.js template seems to work fine without the .erb suffix, but now that you've pointed out its absence I have to admit I don't know *why* it works.